# The operation(s) generations creates an SQL query which exceeds the length limit in Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store

Tags: 2010, bcs

I am trying to add a table from a SQL database as an external content type. When I do so I am getting the following error:

[image: The operation(s) generations creates an SQL query which exceeds the length limit in Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store. The operations(s) will not be generatred. Recreate the operations(s) with less number of columns in the configuration.]

The database table has 188 columns (I did not design this legacy system. I am shocked myself how big that is).

Is there a way I can get BCS to connect to it? I am connecting via SPD would using VS make any difference?

If not I will need to look at creating my own data layer and access the content in a custom web part.

Comment: I am wondering if you ever solved this? can you please share our solution and update this post? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need all 188 columns?

I would create a SQL View or Stored Procedure that interacts only with the data you need.